# Can CAS Server embeded into exist application

Tags: cas

I already have an grails web application, And our project need CAS, however I don't want to setup a standalone server for CAS, So I want to embed the cas server into my grails application, is this possible? and if yes where can I found sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this I suppose by exploding the CAS war and separating it with a seperate context, but I don't think this is the intended usage and you'll end up fighting with the internals of CAS (I've been there!).

Maybe a better solution would be to use the Grails Spring Security plugin?  There's a nice blog entry here:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

This way you could begin with some basic security and later on use the CAS integration if your requirements demand it.

Comment: Is that spring security plugin can only be the client of CAS?

Comment: No you use spring security as your embedded security solution and add cas later on if your needs require.

Comment: If you read that link I added, I believe that spring security can be added as an equivilent of the CAS server with your user data structures being defined within it.  Then later, should you add CAS, spring can also delegate this responsibility to an external CAS server.